# Matlab sort user class array by its property

Tags: matlab, class, sorting

```
classdef MyClass

    properties
        x = 0;
    end
    properties
        y = 0;
    end
    properties
        r = 0;
    end
    methods
    end

end
```

I made an array of `MyClass` of 1 * 100, I want to sort the array by `MyClass.r`. Please give me an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort `MyClass.r` separately and use the previous indices array to rearrange the array of objects:

```
[~,ind]= sort([arr.r]) % arr is the array of objects
                       % ind is the array of previous indices
arr= arr(ind)
```